# including Microsoft redistributable c runtime dlls

Tags: c, winapi

Is it legal to deploy/ship the Microsoft C runtime dlls (from Visual Studio) along with the other exe's and dll's, when the application was not created with Visual Studio.

I want to create a freeware Win32-API-Application. To compile the application I want to use the tcc compiler of Fabrice Bellard.

Now I do not know if I am allowed to include those Microsoft C runtime dlls in my package.

Thank you alot in advance

Please indicate in your answer also, why it is allowed or prohibited, and - if prohibited - if there is an alternative.

Wolfgang

Edit: Iinspectable shows a link in his post that seems to say that one is only allowed to ship/redistribute those files when one has a valid copy of Visual Studio.

```
This is the "REDIST list" that is referenced in the "Distributable Code" section of 
the Microsoft Software License Terms for certain editions of Visual Studio 2013 
("the software"). If you have a validly licensed copy of such software, you may 
copy and distribute with your program the unmodified form of the files listed 
below, subject to the License Terms for the software.
```

So the alternative is to use MinGW which does not need those files in some way?

Comment: C runtime dlls redistributable are freely available from microsoft site, it is OK to include `vcredist_x86.exe` in your product package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a validly licensed copy of Visual Studio you are allowed to redistribute the C Runtime Library together with your application. The CRT is available as executable installers, merge modules, or separate DLLs.

References:

- [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx)
- [Distributable Code for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn501987)

A word of warning, though: The CRT is highly compiler specific. It is not a drop-in replacement for another CRT you do not like. Exception handling, for example, is implemented in part in the compiler and the CRT. If you use a different compiler, you probably will not get exception handling to work. This applies to C++ exceptions as well as SEH exceptions.